# PHP Lamba-style function code throwing a slew of of undefined variable errors

Tags: php, anonymous-function, heredoc

I'm using PHP create_function to make a lamba-style function whose contents are defined by a heredoc style string.  Everything was fine until I moved the code to a Hostgator account.  Something about the Hostgator environment is causing the function to completely fail.

It LOOKS like the heredoc is working fine, and the create_function seems to be executing.  But when the function itself gets called, it dumps a ton of errors claiming every local variable is undefined!  I'm baffled!  Anyone seen this before?   Here's the code:

```
$func_code = <<<EOT
extract( shortcode_atts( array('style' => '','class' => '', 'id' => '', 'gutter' => 'm'), $atts ) );
$col_and_gutter = isset($gutter) ? 'needle-' . $gutter : 'needle-m';

switch ($gutter) {
    case 'ew': $gutter = 'col-extra-wide-gutter'; break;
    case 'w': $gutter = 'col-wide-gutter'; break;
    case 'm': $gutter = 'col-med-gutter'; break;
    case 'n': $gutter = 'col-narrow-gutter'; break;
    case 'none': $gutter = 'col-no-gutter'; break;
}

if ($id != '') $id = 'id="' . $id . '"';
if ($style != '') $style = 'style="' . $style . '"';
$returnval =  '<div ' . $id . ' ' . $style . ' class="col-responsive ' . $col_and_gutter . " " . $gutter . " " . $class . '">';

$returnval .= '<div class="g1"><div class="g2"><div class="g3">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div></div>';
$returnval .= '</div>';
return $returnval;
EOT;            

$func_code = str_replace('needle', $shortcode, $func_code);
$func_handle = create_function('$atts,$content', $func_code); 
add_shortcode($shortcode, $func_handle);
add_shortcode($shortcode . '-n', $func_handle);
add_shortcode($shortcode . '-nn', $func_handle);
```

Here is the error output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: atts in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 129
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: col_and_gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 129
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 129
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 131
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 132
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 133
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 134
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 135
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 136
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 139
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 139
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 139
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 140
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: style in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 140
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: style in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 140
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: style in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: returnval in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: style in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: col_and_gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gutter in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 141
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: class in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 142
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: returnval in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 142
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: content in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 143
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: returnval in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 144
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: returnval in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php
>   on line 145
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in
>   /home3/ade207/public_html/wp-content/themes/armstrongparent/lib/shortcodes.php(148)
>   : runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: `var_dump($func_code)` to see the actual, replaced, function code and see if there's anything unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Passerby.  Thanks, that tipped me off to the problem.

All the $variables were empty blank areas!!  This is because heredoc does automatic variable substitution.  So a person might be wondering how come it worked fine in other environments: GoDaddy and Linode VPS but not on Hostgator...

The reason it broke on Hostgator is because the Heredoc line was originally a Nowdoc when I first uploaded it.  It threw an error so I changed it to Heredoc by removing the single quotes. I wasn't thinking at all and stupidly didn't realize this kicks in variable substitution so all the variables were replaced with null strings instead of staying as string literals for the function code.

Evidentally, Hostgator isn't running PHP 5.3 or later which is why Nowdoc doesn't work.  And really that means I need to modify the script to be more backward compatible anyway.  I might just have to escape all the variables as ugly as that will look.

Comment: I ended up escaping the variables with \ before each $ and that fixed the problem for certain.